# nouveau sched errors filling log

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, nouveau

I am having trouble with Nouveau. As soon as I suspend and resume my laptop, my log fills up with these errors and these files take up GBs within minutes, I then have to restart my laptop to fix this. I installed Nvidia drivers and the problem was fixed, but had then changed it to my integrated Intel card for better battery. Now I can't open Nvidia settings after running `ubuntu-drivers devices` and it gives me an `No Nvidia drivers loaded` error. 
I blacklisted Nouveau hoping to fix the error but that has not had any effect.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

lsmod | grep "nvidia" does not return anything. I am not an expert with Ubuntu and I would really appreciate some help over here
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have an integrated Intel GFX card along with a Nvidia GTX 950M

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

returns the following:

```
    modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

gpu log

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia-modeset.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:1916
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:139a
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver. Skipping...
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-eDP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
The number of cards has changed!
Has the system changed? Yes
System configuration has changed
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: It's already disabled

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe nvidia` output?

Comment: I have edited the question with the output. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: `Linux prejith-K501UX 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`

Comment: And which Nvidia driver did you install? Try to re-install from official repos.

Comment: I installed from the repos. Tried reinstalling them multiple times